# Append <div> using jquery's forEach and templatePlugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, jquery-templates

I'm struggeling for some hours with the following problem:

1. Iterating through a object using jquery's forEach method
2. For each object element, a template should be used, which also fills the information in the template. The plugin, which I am using: [jquery-tempalte](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template#jqueryloadtemplate)
3. For each object the template should be appended to a `<div>`

Unfortunately only the last object element is visualized and loaded to the DOM. All other divs, which are created during the steps before, were overwritten.

**Find here an jsFiddle, which demonstrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/7oq053od/1/**

Do you have any idea, what I am missing?
Would be great to get some feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Options](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template#options) section on the github webpage you can see this third parameter with the `append` property set as `true`.
Just consider add it to your script like this :

```
$.each(results.features, function (key, value) {
    $("#homeView").loadTemplate($("#template"), {
        geoFenceName: value.attributes.title,
        geoFenceDescription: value.attributes.description
    }, {append: true});
});
```

**Here is a working** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7oq053od/6/).

Comment: Wow...that was pretty easy. I've even looked at the documentation, but obviously I've missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For appending multiple div's . you should create a main container that contains all the child div's and when displaying, each div element will be created and append to main container everytime.
Here's a sample code:

```
<div id="container"></div> 

//now in javascript create child div elements and append to main container
<script>

for(var items in data)
{
  var newChild = $(document.createElement('div'));  
    $(newChild).css({
    //some css code
    });
 //now appending it to main container
$('#container').append(newChild);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the template plugin applies the templated values to the same element. If you clone the element, your script works.

```
$.each(results.features, function (key, value) {
    $("#homeView").clone().loadTemplate($("#template"), {
        geoFenceName: value.attributes.title,
        geoFenceDescription: value.attributes.description
    }).appendTo('#fences');
});
```

See updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7oq053od/4/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `loadTemplate` function overwrites the div. You can fix that by cloning the template container and then append it to '#homeWiew'.

I created a fork from your jsfiddle that worked for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/6ksdnejw/